# Does UserPrincipal.ChangePassword count toward password history?

Tags: active-directory, passwords, .net-4.5, change-password

**Does a [UserPrincipal.SetPassword()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.setpassword(v=vs.110).aspx) contribute to a user's password history?**

*This is the administrative version of [UserPrincipal.ChangePassword()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.changepassword(v=vs.110).aspx). SetPassword bypasses password rules (at some level) whereas ChangePassword is bound by the password complexity/length/history requirements.*

We have an application that allows users to reset their password via an application that basically does `SetPassword(tempRandomPassword)` followed by `ChangePassword(tempRandomPassword, newUserPassword)` using the newly entered password. This is to require the user to select a new password that adheres to our password standards of length/complexity/history.

Say we have a password policy is that you can't use the previous X passwords.

**With respect to the password history requirement, if after X SetPasswords, is the X+1th password valid now?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the same test and both SetPassword does count towards the password history. So assuming if you have a policy to set to remember 2 last passwords, and your application does both SetPassword then ChangePassword in 1 action, then AD remembered 2 passwords in 1 action. Subsequently, AD will allow you to set the same previous password.